# Flatten at array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The problem is to try and remove nested arrays:

```
steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]); // should return [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have tried this but the recursion is failing when a nested array appears.

```
function checkElement(el) {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
        if (el.length === 1) {
            return checkElement(el[0]); 
        } else {
            for (var i=0; i < el.length; i++){
                checkElement(el[i]); 
            }  
        }

    } else {
        return (el);    
    }   
}

function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var finalArr = [];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        finalArr.push(checkElement(arr[i])); 
    }  


  return (finalArr);

}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate: this specific question is about an unspecified depth, not about flattening an array of arrays.

Comment: The values in unflatten array could be non-numeric as well?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15030117/402037) from a similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proposal for the first part:

You could change the return value to array and use concat instead of push.

```js
function checkElement(el) {
    // collect the values of the checked array
    var temp = [];
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
        if (el.length === 1) {
            return checkElement(el[0]);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                // collect the values
                temp = temp.concat(checkElement(el[i]));
            }
            // return flat values
            return temp;
        }
    } else {
        return el;
    }
}

// this can be shorten to
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    return checkElement(arr);
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]));
```

Part two, a bit shorter:

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function flat(r, a) {
        return Array.isArray(a) && a.reduce(flat, r) || r.concat(a);
    }, []);
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]));
```

Comment: Thanks I understand the first solution and it passed the tests. The second one I don't follow though I'm sure it also works. If you add comments I might be able to follow it.

Comment: it simply uses Array#reduce with an empty array as start value and a callback which returns either if the element is an array, the values from the call on every element or the value itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce`:

```
function flatten( array ){
  return array.reduce( function (a, b){
    return a.concat( Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b );
  }, [] );
}
```

Comment: I see from your comment on another answer that `flatten` should accept non-array values. I modified the code [here](http://jsbin.com/pecipuzobo/edit?js,console) to return `[]` if the argument is not an array.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be the funniest way to do this and also it's one line no more. Also it leaves extraction to native code which is much faster than Scripting.

```js
var nestedArray = [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]];
var flatten = nestedArray.toString().split(',').map(Number);

console.log(flatten);
```

Comment: You are the khallaghest developer I ever seeen. pashmaaam.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion like this:

```
function flatten(array) {
    var flat = []; //The result array
    //An IIFE that will perform the recursion,
    //is equivalent to: function rec(param) {.....}; rec(param);
    (function rec(a) {
        //For each element in the array:
        //If the element is an array then call the 'rec' function.
        //Else, push it to the result array.
        //I used the conditional (ternary) operator (condition ? expr1 : expr2 )
        for(var i in a) Array.isArray(a[i]) ? rec(a[i]) : flat.push(a[i]);
    })(array);//Initiate the recursion with the main array 
    return flat;//Return the final result
};
```

```js
var a = [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]];


function flatten(array) {
    var flat = [];      
    (function rec(a) {
        for(var i in a) Array.isArray(a[i]) ? rec(a[i]) : flat.push(a[i]);
    })(array);        
    return flat;
};

console.log(flatten(a));
```

Comment: Brilliant, but I just don't understand what you have written.

Comment: I've commented the code. I hope that will help you and I'm always available for further explanations ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator function allows you to efficiently iterate through nested array elements without allocating unnecessary memory. If you really need the flattened array itself, use `[...iterable]` or `Array.from(iterable)`:

```js
function* deepIterate(array) {
  for (a of array) Array.isArray(a) ? yield* deepIterate(a) : yield a;
}

// Iterate through flattened array:
for (a of deepIterate([1,[2,[3]]])) console.log(a);

// Flatten array:
var flat = Array.from(deepIterate([1,[2,[3]]]));
console.log(flat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just return the values, or it wouldn't work when you have arrays of length > 1.

Here's a solution:

```js
function steamrollArray(arr, flattened) {
    if (!flattened) flattened = [];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
         if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
             steamrollArray(arr[i], flattened);
         } else {
             flattened.push(arr[i]);
         }
    }  
    return flattened;
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]])); // should return [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This if it work for you

```
function steamrollArray(unflatenArr) {
    var flatenArr = [];
    if (Array.isArray(unflatenArr)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < unflatenArr.length; i++)
            arrFlat(unflatenArr[i], flatenArr);
    }
    return flatenArr;
}
function arrFlat(arr, refArr) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arrFlat(arr[i], refArr);
        }
    }
    else {
        refArr.push(arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution without using any recursion is by using splice method of Arrays. It works for any level of nesting.

```
function flattenArray(arr){

  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

    if(arr[i] instanceof Array){

      Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr,[i,1].concat(arr[i]))
       i--;
    }

  }

  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function steamrollArray(unflatenArr){
    return eval("["+(JSON.stringify(unflatenArr).replace(/\[/g,'').replace(/\]/g,''))+"]")
}

steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Comment: I was thinking that but the solution has to accept the empty object {} also :/

Comment: that is really a no go solution. because of the replace and finally with eval without emergency.

Comment: If the input is a string this would cause issues.
say for example : [1, [2], 3, "[4]"]